# Spring Boot задержка выполнения метода

Tags: java, spring-boot

У меня есть клиент-серверное приложение. Серверная часть написана на Spring boot.
На сервер посылается целочисленное значение, далее в методе с ним происходят действия, но мне нужно, чтобы метод после вызова выполнялся в течение 10 секунд.
Как я могу это сделать без Thread sleep'ов?

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно, чтобы метод выполнялся определенное время, то можно попробовать так. В переменной lifeTime можно задать время выполнения метода

```
private void someMethod() {
 final long lifeTime = 99999; // время работы метода 
 long startTime = System.nanoTime();
 do {
   // логика вашего метода
 } while(System.nanoTime() - startTime < lifeTime)
}
```